# programatic use of align-regexp causes error

Tags: emacs

My scratch buffer is:

```
(align-regexp 18 76 ";")

( hi   ;;
  this ;;
  is ;;
  my ;;
  thinkdgsklagjn ;;
  )
```

When I evaluate the align-regexp command, I get the error:

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Marker does not point anywhere")

What is wrong with this invocation?
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in that align internals are expecting something like

```
(align-regexp 18 76 "\\(\\s-*\\);")
```

You need a group (to avoid the error) and you need to supply the full regexp with parenthesized whitespace.